# photoswipe custom button raise on browser but not on mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2015, photoswipe

currently working on phonegap mobile development and i am using photoswipe for image gallery but i have an issue. custom button working on ripple emulator but not working on any mobile device my code is.

```
 <button id="btnBookMarks"  title="bookmark" onclick="Download()">BookMark</button>
<script>
        function Download() {
            alert("yes");}
    </script>
```

on ripple `download()` method raise and its alert me but on device nothing happen i think it is bug of photoswipe can you guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience!
I made a work-around by making a text link at the left part of the caption bar below the image with the next code in the items structure:

```
title:  '<a href="javascript:toggleExif()" class="link--exif">Show Exif info</a>' +  'Vooraan: Maria\'s dorp.'
```

Css code:

```
.link--exif {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

See the PhotoSkin sample album: http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PS/

More info: http://jalbum.net/nl/skins/skin/PhotoSwipe